# Why is cellForRowAtIndexPath being called when the cell is not visible?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewController` sitting inside a `Container` which sits inside another `UIViewController`. I built it in a storyboard.
[Here is a snap.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhmtG.png) The `UITableViewController` in question is on the right-hand side and is called `LayerTableViewController`.

For some reason, the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method of this UITableView is being called for cells which are not currently visible. I tested this by changing the method to the following:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("layerCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! LayerTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...

    cell.layerCircleView.layer.cornerRadius = cell.layerCircleView.layer.bounds.width / 2
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: cell.layerCircleView.frame.midX - 10, y: cell.layerCircleView.frame.midY - 10, width: 20, height: 20))
    label.text = String(indexPath.row)
    cell.layerCircleView.addSubview(label)
    print("indexPath.row: \(indexPath.row)")

    return cell
}
```

This code yielded the following odd result. In the console, numbers are being printed occasionally out of order. Cells which are not remotely near the visible screen are having their `indexPath.row` passed in to this method. Furthermore, the `UILabels` that I'm making are all being rendered on top of one another.
[Here is a combined image of the simulator and terminal output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Cjh.png)
As you can see, there is a random line that says `indexPath.row: 0` when the `indexPath.row`s are sitting at around the mid twenties.

So to sum up, why is there a call for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` with an `indexPath.row` that isn't currently visible, and why are the numbers rendering on top of one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm still not sure as to why there were random calls to `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for cells that weren't visible, but that doesn't seem to be a big issue. I thought that and the overlaid rendering were connected but they weren't.

The issue with the overlaid rendering is that all the `UILabels` were being added to a subview of the `UITableViewCell`, namely `cell.layerCircleView`. So as I discovered, when the cell is reused, so too is the reference to the `layerCircleView`. So all I had to do to fix it was clean up the view once it left the screen:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplayingCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = cell as! LayerTableViewCell
    for subview in cell.layerCircleView.subviews {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```